# How to drag/move hour and minutes hand in Analog Clock JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using thooClock jquery library for designing an analog clock which work pretty fine.
https://github.com/thooyork/thooClock

But now I want to move it's hour and minutes hand similar to this website:
https://www.roomrecess.com/Tools/InteractiveClock/play.html

I'm able to click on canvas but not sure how access that specific line stroke

```
$('#canvas').click(function(e){
    console.log('Canvas clicked');
});
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you able to create this in the end? I also need to create this, but in React

Answer (score 0):

From the DOM perspective canvas is a simple element that responds to clicks as a whole. There are sophisticated methods, allowing you to calculate whether you click happened on a hand or not, but it's better to use some higher level libraries to deal with object manipulation over the canvas like fabric.js.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. OP's problem is too broad and ill-defined.